# How to play multiple videos back to back in the same embedded player with the YouTube js API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-javascript-api

So far I have a YouTube player embedded, which I can control via the YouTube API, and I also get the callbacks properly and everything.

So whenever I call `loadVideoById` on my player object to load another video, **while the current one is still playing**,  it works just fine. However, if I call it after a video has stopped, it doesn't do anything.

I have a pre-defined set of YouTube video IDs, that I wish to play one after another in the same embedded player. So what I want, is that once one video stopped, the API issues a callback, so I get notified about it, then I order the player to load another video and play it. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
this.playNextVideo = function playNextVideo() {
    if (this.playlist.length > 0) {
        yt_embedded_player.loadVideoById(this.nextId(), 0);
        yt_embedded_player.playVideo();
    }
}

this.onPlayerStateChange = function onPlayerStateChange(_event) {
    if (_event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) this.playNextVideo();
}
```

- `yt_embedded_player` is my embedded player, as returned by the [iFrame
  API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#IFrame_Player_API)
- `playlist` is the array that contains the video IDs
- `nextId()` is a function that supplies the video IDs one after
  another (from `playlist`)

Is there any method to load and play a video after the previous one reached the end?

Comment: Your code works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/ajt22r72/

Comment: Huh... that's interesting

Comment: Note that I removed the `this` invokations as they were useless in my demo's configuration, but is it in your actual code? Also, do you get any errors in your JS console? (F12 key)

Comment: Okay, I kind of isolated the problem, but I still have no idea what's wrong. The problem seems to be that `if (_event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED)` never evaluates to be true. If I put an alert before this statement, it shows every time there's a change in state, so the callbacks work fine. It's just this if statement that fails to test the value associated with the event.

Comment: Try removing the function name between `function` and `(_event)` and see if something happens, **EDIT:** or, do a console.log of `_event.data` before the `if` statement to see what value it has. `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` should be equal to `0`.

Comment: Nope, same thing. I'm going the check the JS console, hold on...

Comment: It seems like the problem is not the condition, but the call to `playNextVideo()`. It says it's undefined.

Comment: Then, declare it simply like this `function playNextVideo() {` instead of `this.playNextVideo = ...`, make sure the playlist exists and has a positive length. Check that the `nextId()` function returns a value.

Comment: Those are fine, I double checked. Now `_event.data` seems to be undefined somehow, at least that's what the console says. I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Take a closer look at this function in my JS Fiddle, and see if I wrote something differently.

Comment: This is weird... my `nextId()` function is not returning anything when called from inside `onPlayerStateChange()`. It works just fine if I simply call it from somewhere else.

Comment: Just remove `this` in front of it.

Comment: I'll try and remove `this` from everywhere. Actually I only need one player on the site, so there's no point in making this thing a class and instantiating it.

Comment: ... Changed my mind, I don't want to rewrite my whole app. So basically when I specify the 'onReady' and 'onStateChange' callbacks inside "events" (when initializing the youtube player), those functions don't have the "this" context when called. So of course, I call `.bind(this)` on them when handing them over to the youtube api. The "this" context is now okay, but the passed in data (`_event`) is undefined in the call to `onPlayerStateChange`.

Comment: Okay, I found a workaround. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there were two problems actually. One is that when I specified the callback functions to the YouTube API like this:

```
yt_embedded_player = new YT.Player(this.e_id, {
    height: this.player_h,
    width: this.player_w,
    videoId: /* default video id */,
    events: {
        'onReady': this.onPlayerReady.bind(this),
        'onStateChange': this.onPlayerStateChange.bind(this)
    }
});
```

I had to use `.bind(this)` (as you can see) to give meaning to the "this" context within those functions (this is kind of a dumb mistake, but I'm new to javascript, so excuse me for it).

But even so, the argument that is passed to `onPlayerStateChange` was undefined for some reason. That would be that data that describes the current state of the player. So even though the callbacks were dispatched just fine when the player changed state, but the actual state was not passed properly to the function.
So what I did is this:

```
this.onPlayerStateChange = function(_event) {
    if (yt_embedded_player.getPlayerState() == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        this.playNextVideo();
    }
}
```

Instead of relying on the argument, I manually fetch the player's state with the `getPlayerState()` call. This might not be the most optimal, but definitely works.